# Windows Phone GPS Emulator not firing GPS Location Changed event

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, gps, emulation

The title pretty much says it. I have a GPS object with a location changed event registered.

I know that the code works because it logs my position as I move with a real device.

The Windows phone 8 emulator that is in the Visual studio 2012 sdk isn't firing the location changed event though and I don't know why.

I would post code but it's redundant and not the cause. I think the issue is with the emulator. Is there anyone else having this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this is a bug

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/c2cc57b1-ba1f-48fb-b285-d6cfbb8f393a/windows-phone-8-emulator-returns-microsofts-location-only

Here is a work around that kinda works

1. Start your app in emulator
2. Set location
3. Go to the MAPs app on the emulator
4. Click find my location (Wait for it to find you)
5. Go back into your app and see that the new location is updated

You must do this for every move in the emulator you want to make